# Return array with do while loop

Tags: javascript, do-while

Why isn't the myAry being returned 8 times, when num is equal to 7? myAry only returns once with the code below.

```
function array(num) {
   var myAry = ['my array'];
   var i = num;
   do {
     i++;
     return myAry;
   } while (i < 15);
 }

 console.log(array(7));
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help here as there's no context or explanation of the behaviour you want to achieve. I doubt this'll help, but in your code `i` and `num` are essentially redundant, it's functionally equivalent to `var myAry = ['my array']; return myAry;`. Anyways, i'd tag the question with the language you're using and provide a concise explanation of desired behaviour.

Comment: Using Javascript- I'm looking to return the array the number of times between num, and 15. Using a do while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your array function is being called once, it returns the last iteration of the for loop. You need to log to console inside the for loop.

```
function array(num) {
var myAry = ['my array'];
   var i = num;
   do {
     i++;
     console.log(myAry);
   } while (i < 15);
 }

 array(7);
```

If you need to use the returned values somewhere else, you can make use of a two dimensional array.

```
function array(num) {
  var returnAry = [];
  var myAry = ['my array'];
  var i = num;
    do {
      i++;
      returnAry = returnAry.concat(myAry);
    } while (i < 15);
  return returnAry;
}

console.log(array(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are using, but typically the `return` keyword means take what is on the right, send it up to whatever called this function, and continue from there. It essentially ends your function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're calling `return` inside your loop, so the first time your loop runs, it returns `['my array']` and loop never has the chance to execute more than once.
In order to achieve what you're looking for, you need to update the code to this

```
function array(num) {
    var myAry = ['my array'];
    var result;
    do {
       num++;
       // update result based on what you're trying to accomplish here
    } while (num < 15);
    return result;
}

console.log(array(7));
```